# No match for 'operator*' error

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello fellow programmers!

I was going to write a small program for calculating total pay for different periods of time depending on the amount of hours and the salary that the user enters. I managed to make a small bit of the program but when I try to run it and test it I get the following error:

```
Line 33: error: no match for 'operator*' in 'pay * hours_day'
```

I tried doing a google search on this problem but I am really confused on what causes it.

here is my full program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/*

*Program Flowchart*

- Find out how much a worker gets paid per hour, and then find out how many hours they work
a day, and then multiply that to get the total pay in a week or a month or a year.

*/

// global variables

string pay;
float hours_day;


// function that takes the amount of money and calculates the total pay in a week
int total_pay_week() {
    cout << "Type in your salary per hour." << endl;
    cin >> pay;
    cout << "Ok, how many days do you work per day?" << endl;
    cin >> hours_day;

    float total_day = pay * hours_day;

    float total_week = total_day * 7;

    cout << "Your total pay in a week is " << total_week << "if you worked " << hours_day << " per day. " << endl;

}


int main() {

    total_pay_week();

}
```

This is a very early version of my program! I just wanted to know what causes this problem.

Comment: What do you get if you multiply apples with oranges?

Comment: `cout << "Ok, how many days do you work per day?" << endl;` is probably not what you meant to say, either.

Comment: I just realised. A very dumb mistake from me! But thank you both!

Comment: More like... what do you get if you multiply apples with rap music?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Crapple sauce.

Comment: @Alex: Okay, not bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @101010 hints at: `pay` is a `string`, while `hours_day` is a `float`, and while some languages allow you to multiply strings with integers, c++11 (or any other flavor of c) doesn't, much less allow strings and floats to be multiplied together.

Comment: Is C++11 a flavor of C? :P

Comment: @E_net4: It's 11 better!

Comment: C++11 is not "a flavor _[sic]_ of C"

Comment: Guess it depends on how you define "flavors" of languages.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that I declared the pay variable as a string right as I was trying to solve this. Thank you to everyone though! It was a very noobish mistake from me.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `pay` as a `string`.  Change that to `int` or `float` and it should multiply.  The class `std::string` has not * operator for this math, so that explains the error text.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your program code as per below to fix the issue
As Scott suggested you are taking input as string and trying to multiply it with float which is not possible. You need to take input as float and everything would work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**
 * *Program Flowchart*
 *
 * - Find out how much a worker gets paid per hour, and then find out how many hours they work
 *   a day, and then multiply that to get the total pay in a week or a month or a year.
 */

// global variables

float pay;
float hours_day;


// function that takes the amount of money and calculates the total pay in a week
int total_pay_week()
{
    cout << "Type in your salary per hour." << endl;
    cin >> pay;
    cout << "Ok, how many days do you work per day?" << endl;
    cin >> hours_day;

    float total_day = pay * hours_day;

    float total_week = total_day * 7;

    cout << "Your total pay in a week is $" << total_week << " as you are working " << hours_day << " hours per day. " << endl;

}

int main()
{
    total_pay_week();
}
```

Checkout https://ideone.com/mQj3mh for actual running of the code.